# Strongly typed data binding and generics?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-binding, asp.net-4.5

Suppose I want to bind a generic type (here: `Dictionary<string, string>`) to a Repeater using the new ASP.NET 4.5 strongly typed data binding.

Then I would have to put down `KeyValuePair<string, string>` as the ItemType Property of the Repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater id="rpCategories" runat="server" ItemType="System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>">
```

There is an obvious problem here: **I can not use `<` or `>` within the ItemType text!**

How would one go about this? Is the use of generics possible somehow with the new data binding model?

Comment: Tried escaping them with &lt; and &gt;? Any errormessages?

Comment: I haven't tried if that would work when running the page, but VS marks it as an error and Intellisense doesn't work either.

Comment: Nope, does not run either. Error message is obviously that VS is unable to recognize the type.

Comment: I don't see a datasource declared here, so I'm assuming that you're setting it in the code behind. Can you not set the type there as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works for me:

Code behind

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           rpCategories.DataSource = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"1", "item"},{"2", "item"},{"3", "item"},
            };
        rpCategories.DataBind();
        }
```

Markup

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpCategories" runat="server" ItemType="System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String]">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Key %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: This resolved a problem I had for a long time, thanks.