# ASP.NET Strongly-typed DataControl (Repeater) with complex ItemType failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I've got a structure of three nested repeaters to render out a tabs and then under those tabs a number of items grouped by headings. I've been using the strongly-typed data controls in .NET 4.5 successfully on standard `IEnumerable` types but this is my first time with a `Dictionary<T1,T2>`. Nonetheless I've seen another [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250777/strongly-typed-data-binding-and-generics) use a `Dictionary` as the `DataSource` successfully by declaring the `ItemType` as `KeyValuePair<T1, T2>`.

**Markup:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTabs" runat="server"
    ItemType="System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.String, System.Collections.Generic.List<Sitecore.Data.Items.Item>>>">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <%# Item.Key %>
           <%-- ... more repeaters under but they are commented out for now as it's the outer on that is failing --%>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Codebehind:**

```
var myDatasource = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<Item>>>();
// add some items
rptTabs.DataSource = myDatasource;
rptTabs.DataBind();
```

Here's the Exception/Stack trace I'm getting: [image: Yellow Screen]

Appears as if the page can't be built because it can't resolve the ItemType by `string` name. The thing is, I get intellisense on my `<%# Item.Key #%>` so the intellisense engine can resolve the type by string name but the runtime can't?

Note: I doubt it's the `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item` type failing as I've used it before inside an IEnumerable meaning the ItemType was `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I really don't want to write `ItemDataBound` handlers to simply find the inner controls by ID and bind their datasource. Annoying!

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen the ItemType property does not like the `<` angle brackets `>`. The answers I have read have shown that replacing all the angle brackets with their respective square brackets seems to work.

Replace the following:

- `<` with `[`
- `>` with `]`

So you get:

```
ItemType="System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[System.String, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[System.String, System.Collections.Generic.List[Sitecore.Data.Items.Item]]]
```

I was running into a simliar error. However, in my case I found that I was trying to access the `<%# Item.Property %>` from within the `HeaderTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll have a look when I get a chance and come back to mark as the answer if it works.

Comment: Hmm didn't work.. now I get the following when try to access Item.
[New Error](http://imgur.com/2I5Yav3)

CS0305: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>' requires 2 type arguments